# Is time period of a pendulum in an accelerating elevator dependent on the weight of the bob?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, oscillators, equivalence-principle

If a simple pendulum is in an elevator accelerating upwards, Its $T$ decreases. But why is that? The only thing that changes is the apparent weight so does $T$ depend on the weight of the bob but somehow independent of the mass. My guess is that it depends on the weight only when the mass is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as the effective value of $g$ increasing to $g+a$ where $a$ is the upward acceleration of the elevator.

The reverse would be true $g\to g-a$ if the elevator was acceleration downwards, and in free fall, the period $T\to \dots\dots$

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write the equation of motion to prove if your statement holds. The equation of motion reads

$$m \ell \ddot{\theta} = - m (g + a) \sin \theta \ ,$$

so that you can easily realize that this equation and whatever follows from it is independent from the mass $m$.

**Remark.** If you want to think in terms of weight, we should agree on the definition of weight. You can define $W^{in} = m g$ as the measure of a balance in what we agree is an inertial frame, w.r.t. you're measuring acceleration $a$ of the elevator. If you're on the elevator, and have no window to see you're accelerating w.r.t. what everyone agrees to be inertial, and measure the weight with the very same balance used before, your reading is $W^{acc} = m(g+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

In an elevator accelerating by $a$ (+ is up) the bob experiences an acceleration of $g+a$ in place of just $g$. Since $T=2\pi \sqrt{{\cal l}/g}$ an upward acceleration lowers $T$. Note that $T$ is still independent of the mass $m$ of the bob.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g\prime}} \tag{1} $$

Now you are going upwards so

$$ g\prime = g + a \tag{2} $$

where $a =$ acceleration of the elevator. So, if $g\prime$ increases $T$ decreases.

Now, if you want details

$$ T = \frac{2 \pi}{w} \tag{3} $$

with $w$ the angular velocity. Now we assume it as shm so at the extreme position, the acceleration should be max, $acc = - wx^{2}$. And $acc = \left(a + g \right) \sin^{o}$. So,

$$ -wx^{2} = \left( a + g \right) \sin^{o} \tag{4}$$

Now, $w$ is proportional to a, so $T$ is inversely proportional to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if the pendulum system enters into some medium, scan through your basics and work it out to see if it is SHM or not. you will get your answer. Since the elevators only accelerate upward or downward, with respect to the elevator there will be a fictitious force only in the upward or downward direction. So if I assume that the elevator accelerates upward, then the free body diagram looks like this

[image: free body diagram]

The fictitious forces act opposite to the direction of motion of the reference frame. Just to highlight there is no Euler or Coriolis force in this situation. Assuming the length of the string is $l$ and acceleration of the elevator is upwards, writing torque about the hinge, we get

$$ \left( m g + m a \right) l \sin \left( \theta \right) = -m l^{2} \alpha \tag{1} \label{1}$$

$\alpha$ is the angular acceleration and $m l^{2}$ is the moment of inertia about the hinge. Now if the block has an acceleration $a\prime$, then

$$ \alpha l = a\prime \tag{2} \label{2}$$

The minus sign is due to acceleration in the opposite direction of motion.

So, substituting \eqref{2} in equation \eqref{1} and simplifying, we get $m \left( g + a \right) \sin \left( \theta \right) = - m a\prime$. Since angles are small for SHM to hold, we can assume $\sin \left( \theta \right) \approx \theta$ resulting in a differential equation,

$$ \frac{\left( g + a \right)}{l} \theta = a\prime \tag{3} $$

Comparing with $a\prime = w^{2} x$ we get

$$ w = \sqrt{ \frac{\left( g + a \right)}{l}} \tag{4} $$

Now the time period $= \frac{2 \pi}{w}$ where $w =$ angular frequency. You could work this out for the elevator moving up and you will just get the acceleration to be in the opposite direction. If you like to remember some short tricks, for these sorts of situations you could just calculate the net effective acceleration and use the standard pendulum formula $2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g_{\textrm{eff}}}}$. this should answer your question!

Answer (score -3):

The apparent weight, call that $m_g$ changes, but the inertia, $m_i$ does not. So you have to scale the period with some power of $m_g/m_i$.

Comment: all down voters need to take a general relativity class. OP introduced the concept of apparent weight, and only this answer, so far, uses that concept.